# If I create a torrent file on two different sources for the same set of files and specify the same tracker will they be exactly the same?

Tags: bittorrent

I want to create a torrent file for the same set of files but it may end up being created on two or more computers.  I'm wondering if I use the same tracker urls and same piece sizes will these two torrent files will match up exactly.  More specifically, if I have a group of computers and some have the torrent file from host A and others have the torrent file from host B will the tracker recognize that they are all using the same torrent file and thus enable them to share together or will the torrent files be unique for each source they are generated on and thus segment the peers?

Comment: in other words: "are torrent files reproducible?" - mostly. this requires a stable sort order of the input files. this should be easier with v2-only torrents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the same file of which you create the torrents from then they are identical. The generated torrent on both computers will be the same, just make sure you use the same software to generate the torrents.

Make sure you take a hash of both files to make sure they are the same.

Comment: when you say take a hash of both files to make sure they are the same do you mean the files that I am creating the torrent file for? I know that the files I am using to create the torrent file will be identical so am I correct in saying that that will guarantee no matter how many different computers generate the torrent file all peers will still be able to share together?

Comment: Yes as long as it is the same file and a common announce URL you can share it. When I say take the hash I meant indeed the files you are creating your torrent for, sometimes by copying your files there can be copy-errors, thats why.